# Call Groovy method inside Jenkinsfile's environment block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a `Jenkinsfile` that looks like this:

```
static def randomUser() {
  final def POOL = ["a".."z"].flatten()
  final Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
  return (0..5).collect { POOL[rand.nextInt(POOL.size())] }.join("")
}

pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    //CREATOR = sh(script: "randomUser()", returnStdout: true)
    CREATOR = "fixed-for-now"
    ...
  }

  stages {
    ...

    stage("Terraform Plan") {
      when { not { branch "master" } }
      steps {
        sh "terraform plan -out=plan.out -var creator=${CREATOR} -var-file=env.tfvars "
      }
    }

    ...

    stage("Terraform Destroy") {
      when { not { branch "master" } }
      steps {
        sh "terraform destroy -auto-approve -var creator=${CREATOR} -var-file=env.tfvars "
      }
    }

    ...
}
```

My problem is I cannot call `randomUser` while being inside the `environment` block. I would need to have the `CREATOR` variable as a random string every time. I would prefer to have `CREATOR` as a global environment variable since it's going to be used in many `stage`s.

Is there a way to achieve (or workaround) this?

Comment: Given this specific use case, it might better to have `CREATOR` as a parameter, and assign its `defaultValue` using your `randomUser` method.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, that did the trick! Works perfect for me, just make it an answer and I'll happily approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your specific use case, it might be better to use the `CREATOR` variable as a parameter instead of an environment variable, and to assign its `defaultValue` as the return of your `randomUser` method.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters {
    string(name: 'CREATOR', defaultValue: sh(script: "randomUser()", returnStdout: true))
  }
  ...
}
```

You can then use it in your pipeline like so:

```
stage("Terraform Plan") {
  when { not { branch "master" } }
  steps {
    sh "terraform plan -out=plan.out -var creator=${params.CREATOR} -var-file=env.tfvars "
  }
}
```

This way you have a correctly assigned and useful `defaultValue` for `CREATOR`, but with the ability to override it per-pipeline when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by removing environment block and defining global variable `CREATOR` before pipeline block

```
def CREATOR

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Initialize the variables') {
            steps{
                script{
                    CREATOR = randomUser()
                }
            }
        }

        ...
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to start creating dangling variables or another stage just for this (in the configuration)...but thanks for the tip!